# is there any way to put a relative path in the conf files?

Tags: logstash

Well, I've been the following problem .
I've got my workspace the following way

```
bin  conf  example  lib  LICENSE  locales  patterns  README.md  spec  vendor
```

In the conf folder I've got the file `logstash-apache.conf` with the next input

```
input {
  file {
    path => "./../example/logs/logprueba/*_log"
    start_position => beginning   }
  }
}
```

When I run logstash, I get the message:

`File paths must be absolute, relative path specified: ./../example/logs/logprueba/*_log`

Is there any way to put a relative path?

Comment: it's not really a relative path, but since recent logstash [includes support for environment variable expansion in the conf file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html) (may need to pass --allow-env depending on version) if you're willing to always run logstash from a particular directory (the one with the conf file in it, for instance), you could use path => "${PWD}/../example/logs/logprueba/*_log".  Alternatively, if you're willing to set a var, path => "${LOGS_DIR}/*_log"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no -- not without modifying the logstash source code... According to the [docs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#path):

> The path(s) to the file(s) to use as an input. You can use globs here, such as /var/log/*.log Paths must be absolute and cannot be relative.

Comment: Apologies for the downvote. This was probably the best answer 7 years ago but @panchicore's answer below is an effective workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the environment variables using bash `$(pwd)` to yield the current destination, this could not be the master solution for you but at least is not anti-pattern:

`export CSV_FILE=$(pwd)\/temporal_datasets\/dataset.csv`

then in the logstash config file

```
input {
  file {
    path => '${CSV_FILE}'
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    ignore_older => 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm once I got the syntax '${right}'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **linux relative path** then go to file location through terminal and type **pwd** it will give us the relative path of linux system like given below:

```
vikashsingh@CX-BUN-IT-01885:~/Documents/workspace/pw/application-management-system/logging/user-service$ pwd
/home/vikashsingh/Documents/workspace/application-management-system/logging/user-service
```

later on get the path and add /{filename_with_extention}

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/vikashsingh/Documents/workspace/application-management-system/logging/user-service/app.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

It will definitely work because I was getting the same error and followed the same steps. It worked for me. Thanks.